# Find free dictionary with example sentences (e.g. English - German)

Tags: dictionary, translation

Are there free dictionaries available online for download? I have been looking for data which provides multiple possible translations and examples, e.g.:

> Input word: `Nevertheless`
>
> Output: `("Dennoch", "Gleichwohl", "Doch") ; ("The team did not play well; nevertheless, it won the match.","He lost the match; nevertheless, he is a good player.")`

I found some APIs providing translations, but they are not free or don't provide multiple translations or no examples. I am aware that good APIs cost money, but this is due to the fact that they are able to translate whole sentences, which is complicated. I am only interested in translating single words!

Comment: Why don't you buy a good bilingual dictionary? However, this is FREE: https://en.langenscheidt.com/english-german/ and probably the most famous of English<>German dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I personally love to use [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/) because they provide a lot of examples from external sources, which is quite helpful when you are not familiar with a topic. It's not really for download though.
But I just read that you can use their app offline.

Comment: linguee is filled with mistakes. Especially the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

For Japanese (from many other languages) there is the [EDICT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDICT) project.

EDICT had some "children", for example those [listed here](http://nihongo.monash.edu/onlinejdic.html), and then there is [CEDICT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CEDICT) project for Chinese, although I don't know if example sentences are available there.

Bilingual sentence pairs can be obtained from [Tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org) project, from [this link](https://tatoeba.org/eng/downloads) in bulk.

There is [DictionaryForMIDs](http://dictionarymid.sourceforge.net/what.html) project, although I don't know which dictionaries available there (if any) have example sentences included.

There is [FreeDICT](https://freedict.org/) project (same as above, I think the format they're using allows example sentences, but to find out if any are actually included you'll have to check on a case-by-case basis).

There is also [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/dictionaries.php) (I think it can also open FreeDict dictionaries)